# Autosizing the pixel size of text based on text length or size in qml using fontSizeMode

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to use fontSizeMode in qml in order to fix big text in rectangle.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Rectangle
    {
    color: "Red"
    height:50
    width:50

    Text { text: "Hello"; fontSizeMode: Text.Fit; minimumPixelSize: 5; font.pixelSize: 50 }
}
}
```

My aim is to shrink text size if text is bigger than rectangle and a minimum pixel size is given as shown in program. **But text is not shrinking**. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the answer I should use width:parent.width height:parent.height to make it work

working code:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Rectangle
    {
    color: "Red"
    height:50
    width:50

    Text { 
width:parent.width
 height:parent.height
text: "Hello"; fontSizeMode: Text.Fit; minimumPixelSize: 5; font.pixelSize: 50 }
}
```

Comment: It's probably easier to use `anchors.fill: parent` ;-)